# repeat code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code blocks that repeat themselvs.
By writing code blocks I meen html, javascript and css that repeats in many pages.
for example:

```
.filter {
    background-color:black;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[name=aaclick]').click(function(){ alert('aa!'); });
});

<div class="filter">
    aaa<input type="text" />
    <a name="aaclick">click</a>
</div>
```

1. Can I combine those 3 parts of single unit together?
2. How can I prevent myself from writing this code again and again in different pages?

Comment: Do you have some server side language at your disposal? ASP by any change?

Comment: Shadow Wizard is correct; this sure seems like a job for the server although I personally cringe at the thought of ASP (or any other 3 letter acronym ending in P).

Comment: I am using asp.NET but I don't want to rely on server side because all I need are client side.

Comment: sorry but it's like saying "I have a house but I prefer to live in my car". Server side code is much better to rely on than client side. If you insist on such thing it's your call though.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Using server side here is like using tank in order to crush a bug. I have client side problem and I want to solve it in the client side.

Answer (score 1):

*Can I combine those 3 parts of single unit together?*
You *can* make them closer to each other (reduce number of parts to 2, at least), but I wouldn't recommend that. Styles should stay with styles, javascript with javascript and html with html.

*How can I prevent myself from writing this code again and again in different pages?*
 1. Put this style definition in a common css file, included in every page. Do not repeat.
 2. Put this javascript code in a common js file, included in every page. Do not repeat.
 3. You can reduce third part to `<div class="filter"></div>`, if you generate the rest of the content from javascript. Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filter').each(function() {
        $(this).append('aaa').append($('<input/>').attr('type', 'text'));
        ...
        $(this).find('input[name=aaclick]').click(...);
    })
});
```

Now, you can put only `<div class="filter"></div>` in html, the rest will be autogenerated.

Comment: do you meen actually to create a plugin for such common code?

Comment: @Naor You may call it 'plugin', if you like. I was just reducing the amount of duplication, since you said you use this code 'again and again in different pages'.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some templating tools.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_(web)#Example find a template engine for the language that you are using and take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to split them into a css, js and html file, named appropriately so you know they are related.

Then use code to add them to your page, using a standard method, thus allowing you to keep the functionality together.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `ASP.NET` simply build user control, put the whole "repeated" block as-is in the `.ascx` file then wherever you need it to appear have `<UC:MyBlock runat="server" />` and that's it - reliable in 100%, flexible.. really no reason  to mess around with client side templates, jQuery plugins and such.

Comment: Why is user control better then jquery plugin? - this is my main indecision.

Comment: @Naor - jQuery is not perfect and in the end of the day, it's client side JavaScript with all its downsides... using server side control will always send the same HTML output to all the browsers.